# Yodlee – credit card transaction – transaction location

Tags: transactions, yodlee

Has anybody tried or been able to get credit card transaction locations (country/state/city when card present) via Yodlee data feed?  Such information is available in the credit card bank statements but I am not sure if available via Yodlee.

Answer (score 0):

Currently transaction location information is not directly available via Yodlee data feed. If such information is available in the transaction description then you can parse the transaction description available via Yodlee and retrieve the location of the transaction.